# How to convert .py to .exe in Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, py2exe, py2app

I've developed an application in Python with PyQt on Mac OS and I want to make .exe file for windows OS. How can I do this?

I've tried in Ubuntu but it doesn't work. I'll be grateful for some useful assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Alright…
So in Mac, there is a simple way to convert .py to .exe.
In terminal first open the file directory with the “cd” command
i.e. cd Desktop/MyFile
Then run this code:
pyinstaller —onefile name.py
Instead of “name.py” put your own file.
After that, in the same folder there will be created a  “dist” file, you can find the ready .exe there…)