# How make ".exe" file from python file on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I have MacBook on apple silicon and I need make ".exe" file from python file.
I have tried use pyinstaller, but it give error:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/osx.py", line 211, in fix_exe_for_code_signing 
    assert linkedit_seg.fileoff + linkedit_seg.filesize == \
AssertionError: Sanity check failed!
```

How can I make ".exe" file. Also I need to use multiple python and other files.

Comment: Maybe you can try `auto-py-to-exe`

Comment: use golang instead of python if you wanna do good cross compilation :)

Comment: This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55255421/how-to-convert-py-to-exe-in-mac

Comment: @mama I didn't think that I would have to create an ".exe" when I wrote the program

Comment: You can't cross-build Python. It's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.exe files are for windows only. If you want to make an executable file on Mac, then you have to convert it to .app not .exe. Refer to this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVOoHL2Bp_o&t=211s .